# Magento Coupon Code generation problem

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created module and trying to generate the coupon code,but here it generate the two coupon code, If I set 'qty => 10', then it generating 20 coupons. What things missing out here ?

Code:

```
public function getCouponCodecustom(){

try {

    $data = array(
        'rule_id' => 123,
        'qty' => 1,
        'length' => 8,
        'format' => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
        'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
        'uses_per_customer' => 1
    );
    $generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
    $generator->setData($data);
    $generator->generatePool();

} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with coupon: %s', $e->getMessage()));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with coupon.'));
  }
}
```

I have used the function in Newsletter template as follows:

```
Newsletter Subscription Success

{{if subscriber.couponCodecustom}}
Thank you for subscription, your coupon code <b>" {{var subscriber.couponCodecustom}} "</b>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Hi, looking at the `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon_Massgenerator::generatePool`, I don't see any reason why your coupon are created twice : can you tell us how you launch this script : is this by cron, or a shell script, or in a controller action ? Maybe you could add some `Mage::log('here')` in your code to see how many time your method is executed (should be only one log but  I guess you will see two logs). Maybe your script is executed for each store or something like that ?

Comment: Please check  I have updated the question, I debugged more and tried with removing the if condition, then it works perfectly,the if condition making the function to exectute twice, first it executed during condition check and second inside the "if" condition. I feel thats the reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged more and tried with removing the if condition, then it works perfectly,the if condition making the function to execute twice, first it executed during condition check and second inside the "if" condition. I feel thats the reason